# gitolite hook after git push doesn't work

Tags: hook, gitolite

I tried to search to find a solution. 
but, I can't.

I installed gitolite. And it works well.
I can git clone on the local machine, and change gitolite-admin repo too.

But I want to use gitolite hooking.
followed this manual

http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/hooks.html

> **custom hooks**
>
> You can supply your own, custom, hook scripts if you wish. Install
>   gitolite as usual, then:
>
> go to ~/.gitolite/hooks/common on the server and put your new hook
>   there now run "gl-setup" again You can use this procedure to install
>   new hooks as well as to update hooks that you had previously
>   installed.

So I tried to hook some basic shell script.

I put bash shell script on

```
~/.gitolite/hooks/common
```

and named it

```
update
```

update script file's owner is git, and excutable.
the shell script is like this..

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/$GL_REPO
```

and I execute

```
gl-setup mypubkey.pub
```

and then,
On my local git folder,
I modified some file, `commit` and `push` to gitolite server. 
push works well. every file uploaded to the gitolite's repo.
but, hooking doesn't seems to occur. Nothing happened.

on the server's tmp directory, no file is created.

Did I forget something?

any comments plz...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should realize that (from the "[using hooks](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/hooks.html)" page you mention in your question=:

> The `update` hook is used in all repos and is critical to gitolite's access control

In other words, you cannot *directly* use an "update" script.
You must use the "[**hook chaining**](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/hooks.html#hookchaining)" feature of gitolite, in order to call your own update hook *after* the one of gitolite:

> To run your own '`update`' hook, just put it in a file called **`update.secondary`** and install it as a hook.
>   Gitolite's `update` hook will automatically chain to it, taking care to pass it the same 3 arguments the original `update` hook received from git.

---

In the end, the [OP Jinbom Heo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505345/jinbom-heo), rather than using "gitolite hook chaining", went with another hook:

> I put **`post-receive`** file in `/var/gitolite/hooks/common/` folder. And it works.

The doc "[Where do I put my hooks](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/hook_prop.html#hook_propagation_so_where_do_I_put_my_hooks__)" suggest rather to put those under the "user" location (`~/.gitolite/hooks/common`):

[image: hook place]

But the system location works too.

( `/var/gitolite/hooks/common/` means, by the way, the OP chose the [root method installation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/root.html) or the [package one](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rpmdeb.html), with the default paths `/usr/local/bin`, `/var/gitolite/conf`, `/var/gitolite/hooks`)

Comment: thank you VonC always. ^^;

You give me a decisive hint.
I put post-receive file in /var/gitolite/hooks/common/ folder. 
and it works. 

thank you.

Comment: @JinbomHeo Excellent. I have included your solution in the answer for more visibility, and have added a reference to the relevant documentation, for others to see.